# How can I access hdfs on hadoop-yarn application from each node?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

How do I access HDFS and read and write files from each node in the "HADOOP (2.5.2) YARN Application"? I usually know that YARN applications run on HDFS. I do not have a website or document that answers these basic questions, so I ask.

Comment: What do you mean you have no website? Read the Hadoop page or buy the Definitive Guide book http://hadoop.apache.org/

Answer (score 1):

YARN applications run (or at least request memory space)  **in YARN**, not HDFS.

HDFS is only a filesystem for file storage. You read and write using many tools, such as the Hadoop CLI, MapReduce, Apache Spark, etc.

The CLI for example is `hadoop fs -put /local-file hdfs://remote/file`

Whether those applications are managed by YARN is unrelated to how HDFS files are accessed.

You do not need YARN for HDFS. It is entirely separate and used for a memory **R**esource **N**egotiator (it's in the name). Whichever node a YARN container is ran on could be an HDFS datanode within a Hadoop environment, but that's not always true - it's just good design as the data would be `NODE_LOCAL` in HDFS terms, so no data needs shuffled around the cluster.

Comment: Do you mean that I can not access HDFS at the code level of YARN APPLICATION?

Comment: What makes you think I said that?

Answer (score 0):

In a map-reduce action java based or streaming, Spark etc.; all HDFS is accessible to YARN running program as native file storage. So like your local file storage just read the data stored using usual file read commands. For example in R streaming:

```
path1 <- paste0("hadoop fs -getmerge /apps/hive/warehouse/",hive_db,".db/dsp/mdse_dept_ref_i=",dept,"/mdse_clas_ref_i=",clas,
                " dspD",dept,"C",clas,".txt")
system(command = path1)
filename <- paste0("ItemSlsD",dept,"C",clas,"SC",sbcl,".txt")
item_sls <- data.table(read.table(filename,sep="\001"))
```

Here I am just reading HDFS folder using `hadoop fs -getmerge` and then pasting it in a file. this is followed by putting that file into `data.table` data structure in R. Same way you can issue HDFS command using `subprocess` package in python and store result in `pandas`.

Answer (score 0):

Read the [HDFS Users Guide](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsUserGuide.html). There are numerous client libraries like [libhdfs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/LibHdfs.html), use the [FileSystem](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html) API from Jaav, you can use the [WebHDFS](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html) Rest API, fork to shell and do [commands](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSCommands.html). If your 'YARN application' is a M/R app then all this is already handled by M/R and you only need consume the input you're given.